# Одна Activity или две Activity?

Tags: java, android, activity

У меня есть `Activity` в которой пользователь создает/заполняет форму (Выбирает даты, выбирает значения из выпадающего списка, заполняет `EditText`), эти все данные сохраняются в БД (после нажатия на кнопку "Готово"). После этого - формы добавляются в `ListView` и у пользователя должна быть возможность просмотреть созданные формы (без возможности их редактирования) по нажатию на `Item` в `ListView`. По сути,(`layout`) дизайн и расположение View не меняются, на экране создания и просмотра формы выглядят одинаково, кроме того, что в форме создания можно вносить данные, а в форме просмотра можно только их просматривать. Вопрос: для экрана просмотра форм лучше сделать отдельную `Activity`? Или оставить одну `Activity`, но сделать два режима? и в режиме просмотра просто запрещать ввод текста `(EditText.setFocusable(false)`, выбор даты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если все виджеты идентичны, то нет никакой надобности делать точно такую же активити.

Достаточно одной активити с режимом просмотра и редактирования.